# Add numpy array to pandas dataframa

Tags: json, pandas, numpy

I try to add an array of my prediction scores with the key 'prediction' to an existing dataframe and save it in a JSON file. I get no issue but nothing happens. What's going wrong?

```
df_pred = pd.DataFrame(pred, columns=["prediction"])

frames = [df_Origin, df_pred]
df_merged = pd.concat(frames)

mergedJSON = df_merged.to_json(employeeFolder + '/predictionData.json', orient='records')
```

Comment: please produce a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the data frame you want to add pred vector is named df; try to use:

```
df['prediction'] = pred
```

it will make a column in df named "prediction" and assign pred vector values to this column.